# jQuery if and $(this) confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

Something that has been bugging me for a while.

**JavaScript**

```
$('.video-tab-container ul li a').click(function(e) {
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
    console.log(thisClass);
    if ( $('.video-container .video').is('.' + thisClass) ) {
        $(this).addClass('test');
      }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="video-tab-container clearfix">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="chinese" href="#">Chinese</a></li>
        <li><a class="thai" href="#">Thai</a></li>
        <li><a class="english" href="#">English</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="video chinese"></div>
    <div class="video thai"></div>
    <div class="video english"></div>
</div>
```

Within the if statement, how do I make `$(this)` the element within the if statement? So, if the statement is true, the class `test` is added to the `.video` with the corresponding class? Maybe I am doing this all wrong.

Comment: $(this) will always refer to the calling statement - try `var x = $('.video-container .video')` and then using `x.addClass` etc

Comment: There is no special scope in if statements, so you can't make `this` the element in the statement, you have to refer to it by it's selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think replacing your if statement with this:

```
$('.video-container .video.' + thisClass).addClass('test');
```

will do what you're trying to do. Like the commenters above said, the "if" statement doesn't change what "this" refers to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
$(this).closest('.video-tab-container').next()
       .find('.video.' + thisClass).addClass('test')
       .siblings('.video').removeClass('test');
```

instead of:

```
$(this).addClass('test');
```

because currently `$(this)` is treated as your clicked anchor.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H34bH/)**

Answer (score 1):

The reference to `this` isn't going to change just because it's within an `if` statement.
If you want the reference to `this` to change the statement needs to be written like this:

```
$('.video-tab-container ul li a').click(function(e) {
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
    console.log(thisClass);

    $('.video-container .video').each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.is('.' + thisClass) ) {
        $this.addClass('test');
      }
    })

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Note:  It is cleaner to simply assign `var $this = $(this)` then it is to wrap `$(this)` every single time you need it.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher True. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: It just seems easier to just target the class directly, as in Felix answer ?

Comment: Sure, but that wasn't really the question

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.video-tab-container ul li a').click(function(e) {
    var thisClass, video;
    thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
    console.log(thisClass);
    if ((video = $('.video-container .video.' + thisClass)).length !== 0) {
        $(video).addClass('test');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: is() returns true or false, not an element ?